# Orchard cms,create a list of selected content on admin menu

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to make a list of a specific content type by making a query and show the list on the admin menu. I created a projection to associate the query and added to the admin menu. But when I click on the menu created, it navigates to the edit mode of the projection definition but I was expecting a list. Can anybody help how to create a list of selected content type which can access from admin menu?

Regards
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are examples of code adding custom lists of content items in Vandelay.Industries. The repo for Vandelay can be found [here](https://github.com/bleroy/vandelay/).

The way it works is that it actually just creates admin menu items that point to the existing `Admin` controller in the `Content` feature that displays lists of content items. That controller is already equipped for filtering items by content type.

```
item.Action("List", "Admin",
    new RouteValueDictionary {
        {"area", "Contents"},
        {"model.Id", definition.Name}
    })
```

You can [find the controller in question in the Orchard repo](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Core/Contents/Controllers/AdminController.cs), if you want to write your own version for your own specific purposes (but again, you don't need to if you just want to display items filtered by type in the admin in a way consistent with the rest of the dashboard).

The relevant code is this:

```
_contentManager.Query(versionOptions, model.TypeName);
```

Comment: Here is the <a href="http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries">Link</a> to what Bertrand is talking about in the Orchard Module Gallery. You don't have to write any code do what you want.

Comment: An example of code would be much more useful than broken links or reference to libraries (modules) that are not in the main orchard distribution

Comment: I updated the already accepted answer. You can remove your downvote.