# Orchard cms, how to make a list of content items on admin menu

Tags: orchardcms

Can somebody help me finding any sort of doc, how to make a list of content item on the admin menu.

Regards
George

Comment: possible duplicate of [Orchard cms,create a list of selected content on admin menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518171/orchard-cms-create-a-list-of-selected-content-on-admin-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Any content item can be promoted to the admin menu if there is the Admin Menu Part on its content type. Projections have this part by default.

That doesn't necessitate any coding, but if you want to see how to add a custom list of contents from code to the admin menu, there are examples of that in Vandelay.Industries.

Comment: When projection is promoted, I get the edit link of the projection instance. Is there any way can I show the projection listing in admin other than creating a custom listing by code?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a query to the ContentManager with the criterions you want:

```
var query = _contentManager.Query( //your query);
```

This method has a ton of overloads and extension overloads, so you should find one that suits your needs.

For an exemple of use, try looking at the source from the Contents AdminController ([see source](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/cba63b605e53#src/Orchard.Web/Core/Contents/Controllers/AdminController.cs)), it does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So there is no on the fly creation of list using query and projection modules. so that I can show the list on the admin menu.

Comment: Projections are meant to show their selections on the client side. As far as I know, there is no way of creating a custom content item list in the admin without coding. You can always create a query and preview its results admin-side, but the results will be displayed as if it were on the client side.